# Правильно ли происходит освобождение памяти? C++

Tags: c++, утечка-памяти

Допустим есть такой метод в классе:

```
double* MyClass::my_method() {
    
    double *d = new double(1.9);
    return d;

}
```

И потом его вот так вызывают:

```
MyClass obj = MyClass();
double *d2 = obj.my_method();
```

То что произойдет, если удалить d2 при помощи delete d2? Освободится ли память или будет утечка?

Comment: Да, все правильно. `delete d2;` не "удаляет d2". Он удаляет то, на что тот указывает.

Comment: Ну да. Просто я подумал, что такой указатель будет указывать на адрес того, что вернула функция. То есть будет указатель на указатель на память.

Comment: Указатели на указатели выглядят вот так: `double **x;`.

Comment: Утечка будет, если вы его **не** удалите :)